# jQuery efficiency question

Tags: jquery

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="best">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <span>title</span>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <span>title</span>
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <span>title</span>
</div>
```

I want jQuery code to remove all spans. Which is best:

```
$('#best').find('span').remove();
```

or

```
$('#best').children('span').remove();
```

or

```
$('#best').find('span').each().remove();
```

or is there a better solution? Which is best?

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#best span').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for readability:

```
$('#best > span').remove()
```

Comment: I dont care about readability, only efficiency matters to me. WOuld you say this is the most efficient? Thanks.

Comment: If you benchmark all of these, you'll find that this is as good as any of the examples you provided.

Comment: @U22199: You should always care more about readability and maintainability than performance. Premature optimization is, as is often quoted, the root of all evil. Only worry about it if it's causing significant performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

**1** and **3** are identical. **2** is different in that it only removes direct descendants of `#best`, while the other two will remove descendants at any level. It's really up to you whether you use `find` or `children`, as it depends on your intentions, but there's no need for `each`.

You can, however, contract the whole thing into the selector, so **1** would become `$('#best span').remove();` and **2** would become `$('#best > span').remove();`.

Comment: what would you say about @derek's solution?